# Filter in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I came accross to this python exercise with df as following:

```
   text_A             text_B 

0 LOVE it          love. it 
1 Make. It. Nice   make. it. (nice) 
2 Just do it       you can make it 
3 Just do it       you can make it
```

When i used this code :
`df[df.text_B == "love. It"]`, it will return as what I expected:

```
   text_A             text_B 

0 LOVE it          love. it
```

But, what if I want to filter the df based on column 'textB' values so that it will only return rows that have 'love. it' and 'make. it. (nice)' in the new df?

```
   text_A             text_B 

0 LOVE it          love. it 
1 Make. It. Nice   make. it. (nice)
```

I used `df[df.text_B == "love. it|make. it. (nice)"]`, but it doesn't work, i think it has to do with the '(nice)'.

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You almost got it `df[df.text_B == "love. It" | df.text_B == "make. it. (nice)"]`

Comment: You can also use:  `df[df.text_B.isin(['love. it', 'make. it. (nice)'])]`

Comment: Take care of case: `"love. It"` is not the same as `"love. it"`

Comment: Thanks all! @Ch3steR, i tried the suggested code in jupyter notebook but it gives me this error message:TypeError: Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool].

Comment: @Muhammad Hassan, the code only displays row for 'make. it. (nice)' not both.

Comment: @Corralien, typo on my end, sorry.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan, it works, earlier it did not work because of the typo. Thanks!